# Can I use a hollow-wall anchor in between two nearby holes from previous anchors?

Tags: drywall

Sorry for my OCD, but "it is what it is": I hung a 22 lb. clock with a plastic toggle (drywall), then saw it was too high. I put a new toggle anchor in about 1-1/16"   lower (in other words, very very slightly more than an inch, certainly not less-- but very close to an exact inch).

I was shocked that moving it a mere inch lower had such an extreme effect, normally I hang things casually and am satisfied. But the clock gets a very different look from a small change.

As you guessed, I would love to hang it exactly in the middle, but naturally worry about all these holes, drywall not being steel -or even wood.

Can I somehow (using a drill, large bit, brute force, but carefully to minimize collateral impact) remove the old toggles, fill with drydex (or some form of epoxy), and start from scratch with a new hole (and anchor) exactly in the middle where I want it? Or would leaving the toggles in place be structurally stronger for the wall than attempting that "surgery"?

Or is it just a bad idea, too risky, to try to put a new hole/anchor exactly between my earlier attempts that are only an inch apart?

Is there a solution such as trying to reinforce the wall in that area somehow (thin metal plate, eg, which will be invisible anyway)? Or by using an extra hanger placed above, to take on some of the load from an unstressed section, about two inches higher).

Thanks for any tips, clarifying a bit how strong or weak that drywall is, and what it can stand (and weight it can safely hold) in such a situation.

Thanks again, 
Andrew

Comment: Your followup questions are too broad with us knowing nothing about the clock or its mount. Also, we're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Please don't ask new questions in comments or substantially change your question without revising the original post.

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses (though disappointing). Unfortunately, can't move right-left; it's dead-center on a narrow wall; that would be less attractive. And sadly can't reposition/substitute the clock mount. Is there any way to extend (by attaching something rigid to) the mount, adding a half inch to the loop? I'm thinking steel wire, then using a wide steel plate to keep the hanger (also with toggle anchors) pressed against the wall. Must be a better solution! Thanks again!  ....But if I were determined (im not, as yet) to make a new hole in between, what *would* be the best approach?

Comment: is the any way that you can adjust the attachment on the back of the clock? ...... maybe a loop of aircraft cable and hang it on a hook that is higher than the one you just put in the wall ........... better still, post a picture of the back of the clock

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise against even trying. 22 lbs. is quite a lot for a single anchor, and the drywall between the two previous attempts is compromised. I'd not be surprised if it tore right out of a third hole.

Gypsum wallboard is fairly strong until 1) the paper facing is compromised, and 2) the gypsum material inside is disintegrated. After that, it's mush.

At this point you have some options, which I'd try in this order:

1. Ignore it for three days, then decide whether it's actually a problem.
2. Adjust or modify the mount on the clock to move its position instead.
3. Use anchors to mount a thin plate over and below the existing holes. Use an anchor through both the plate and the drywall.
4. Open the wall, install a horizontal backer block between studs, and repair the drywall and paint.

Comment: Thanks, these confirm my own logic on the matter, including the plates, and suspicion about the wall's fragility. I'll probably try a solution involving a new mount- i probably exaggerated how hard that would be. Will probably involve taking the movement out temporarily to anchor the new hanger to the clock. Won't be fun, but worth it. I'll follow the 3 day wait idea first!

Answer (score 2):

Cut a slot between the two anchors and remove them. clean the back of the slot so that the are no protrusions.

take a strip of plywood (or MDF) as long as your wall cavity is deep and as wide as the height of the slot.

drill a small hole in the centre of the plywood and put a knotted sting through  Apply 
paneling or wallboard adhesive to the side with the string and the put it inside the wall. pull the string so that it sticks to the back of the wall-board.covering the back of the slot.

once the glue is fully cured cut off the string drill a hole and fit a screw or screw-hook to hang the clock. fill the slot using plaster repair compound .and paint it (if needed)

drill that hole even if using self drilling screws, the less pressure you put on the plywood the better.